# How to know the file from command "docker change" is regular file or directory

Tags: docker

We can get a list of files from command "docker containerID change" to watch the container changes. Can I know that each file in the list is a regular file or directory?

Input"
GET /containers/4fa6e0f0c678/changes HTTP/1.1

Output:
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json

[
     {
             "Path": "/dev",
             "Kind": 0
     },
     {
             "Path": "/dev/kmsg",
             "Kind": 1
     },
     {
             "Path": "/test",
             "Kind": 1
     }
]

Comment: what you tried until now?

Comment: I only need a list of changed files but not their parent directories. The command output list the changed files and parent directories.

Comment: paste your code, we can help you fix it. try to create a list of all items and remove folders from it.

Comment: The RestAPI is "GET /containers/4fa6e0f0c678/changes HTTP/1.1". And the output is [ { "Path": "/dev", "Kind": 0 }, { "Path": "/dev/kmsg", "Kind": 1 }, { "Path": "/test", "Kind": 1 } ].   Is there a parameter to only list the changed files? Or is there a property I can know that it is a file but not directory? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The output of the docker change api is a list of all modified files/directories. In linux when a file modified, it's directory is modified as well. if you need to extract only files, you can remove all parents distinguished with their names. like this:

Consider a file name `/use/share/my_file` changed. It shows in api as:

```
[{ "Path": "/usr/share/my_file", "Kind": 0 },  
 { "Path": "/usr/share", "Kind": 0 },  
 { "Path": "/usr", "Kind": 0 }]
```

So if you want to extract file only you should split each Path and check in any one is it's parent:

```
["usr","share","my_file"],["usr","share"],["usr"]
```

or even easier, foreach Path, remove all paths contains in this path:

for `/usr/share`: `/usr` is contains in first one, so you can remove it.
for `/usr/share/my_file`, `/usr` and `/usr/share` are contains in the path and con be removed.

Start to do it your self and if any issue remains, we can help to solve it.